# iOS- Change of UITextField height and movement of Buttons based on keyboard display

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am having an view in iOS where there is an UITextfield and 3 UIbuttons below the UITextField. Please see below for the pic. When this view is launched, the default state is STATE1.(Please see image). The keyboard is visible by default. Now when I dispose the keyboard, I wish to have the edittext resized and occupy the whole screen as shown in STATE2.

I am not sure how to accomplish this. I have the height of the UITextfield hardcoded to some dp based on the target device. I believe this has to be changed and it has to dynamically occupy the screen based on the screen size. [image]

Can anyone help me accomplish this. Please consider the button is like a tail to the edit text. This clings to the edit text no matter the keyboard is visible or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) library and achieve this what you want.

Comment: Reading it. Will get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> First you have to use UITextView instead of UITextField

The register your class for

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Implement this methods

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self resizeViewWithOptions:[notification userInfo]];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification  {
    [self resizeViewWithOptions:[notification userInfo]];
}

- (void)resizeViewWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options {   

    NSTimeInterval animationDuration; 
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame;
    [[options objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[options objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[options objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;

    CGRect keyboardFrameEndRelative = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame fromView:nil];
    NSLog(@"keyboardFrameEndRelative: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(keyboardFrameEndRelative));

// Now set Frame for UITextView and UIbuttons frame here

}
```

Comment: Hi Bhuvaneshwar, Where  do we need to register for the class. Could you please let me know. What is addObserver here? Thanks

Comment: @TimothyRajan In your class itself you have to write this method. Register your class for Keyboard notification in `viewdidLoad' and define this method in same  class. Here `addObserver` behaves as a target.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this even simpler first add those controls what you want which looks like in state 1

in viewDidAppear add the following function

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.Textfield1 becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

so it will load keyboard when the view loads

then add this lines to .m to close the keyboard press return it will hide keyboard

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    //Write your coding for resizing size dynamically to show look like state 2
    //Here check version of device to set as per height
    textfield.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,400);
    button1.frame=CGRectMake(0,400,320,400);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;

}
```

don forget to add delegate for textfield